# 401 Unauthorized using devise after adding theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have the error **Completed 401 Unauthorized in 99.0ms** after adding a template in rails 3.2 app and i was signing in from /users/sign_in URL.

Also, i did not change anything like authenticate by "name" but using the defaults authentication by email address.

Does anyone encounter this problem when signing in?

The error is:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-05 12:04:19 +0800

Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<removed>", "user"=>{"email"=>"zaihan@clixster.net", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}

  ESC[1mESC[35mUser Load (1.0ms)ESC[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'zaihan@clixster.net' LIMIT 1

Completed 401 Unauthorized in 14.0ms

Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<removed>", "user"=>{"email"=>"zaihan@clixster.net", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}

  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (38.0ms)

  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.0ms)

  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Make sure you do not have

```
attr_accessor :password
```

or your password field for devise in database would be empty.